# Unable to add to an array of objects copied from state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a list of file names populating in the UI. I'd like to add to this list on the front end (**that.state.selectedReq.userUploads**) after a file is uploaded to the API. Im creating a copy of what's in state with **let userFiles = Object.assign** and then want to iterate through the list of files to upload and add them to the copy of the array of what's in state. I then want to setState with the new array. However, I'm erroring out on the line **userFiles.push(upload);** and I'm not sure why.

```
var i = 100;
let userFiles = Object.assign({}, that.state.selectedReq.userUploads);
that.state.selectedFiles.forEach((x) => {
  let upload = {
    documentName: x.name,
    userUploadId: i,
    notes: "undefined"
   };
    i--;
    userFiles.push(upload);
  })

  that.setState({
    uploadFileInProgress: false,
    userUploads: userFiles
  })
```

Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: Can you show the error you said you're getting?

Comment: What is the error message what you get there?

Comment: `userFiles` is not a list.

Answer (score 3):

[Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) returns an object, use spread operator to copy the array in state.

```
let userFiles = [...that.state.selectedReq.userUploads];
```

Answer (score 0):

`.push()` is a method of an array, not an object. `Object.assign()` will generate an object, that's why your code is erroring out.

If your `state.selectedReq.userUploads` is an array, you can do this:

```
let userFiles = that.state.selectedReq.userUploads.slice();
...
userFiles.push(upload);
```

If your `state.selectedReq.userUploads` is an object, you can do something like this:

```
let userFiles = Object.assign({}, that.state.selectedReq.userUploads);
...
userFiles[x.name] = upload;
```